# Check if a path will fail due to open_basedir

Tags: php, open-basedir

Is it possible to check this before failing ?

```
if (is_in_open_basedir($path)) {
}
```

Comment: This is a good question because I don't think you can do a robust check without using [realpath](http://www.php.net/realpath)(), but realpath() is itself subject to open basedir.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ini_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) to get the current value of open_basedir to check against the other value.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not answer the question exactly, but maybe the motivation behind it:

If you do not need to check *before* the call and just want to avoid warnings, on functions that access other dirs, another approach would be to use the `@` operator and check `error_get_last`

```
error_clear_last();
$isDir = @is_dir('/');
if (error_get_last() !== null) {
   $isDir = 'cannot-detect';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is not a php standard function.
To handle exceptions you can use:

```
try {

}
catch( $e ) {

}
```

Check this: [PHP Exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that there is an exception here that could get caught?